# How do I correctly use the DistanceBetween method to return JSON objects within a radius?

Tags: android, json

I have the following code and basically I am wondering how I can use this location method distanceBetween() to find the objects in my .JSON file that are under 500km away. I tried to craft together an if statement and a distanceBetween usage but it doesn't recognize it and I know my syntax has some real problems. Is this the right way to be trying to do this? Any help or tips or code is greatly greatly appreciated!

```
package com.dredaydesigns.radiostationfinder;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
   // String HTTPRadioURL = "https://transition.fcc.gov/fcc-bin/fmq?state=&call=&city=&arn=&serv=FC&vac=3&freq=0.0&fre2=107.9&facid=&asrn=&class=&dkt=&list=0&dist=100&dlat2="
       //     + latitude + "&mlat2=&slat2=&NS=N&dlon2="
        //    + longitude +"&mlon2=&slon2=&EW=W&size=9";


    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RadioData mRadioData;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    @Bind(R.id.longitudeLabel) TextView mLongitudeLabel;
    @Bind(R.id.latitudeLabel) TextView mLatitudeLabel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_content);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        double latitude = 32;
        double longitude = -96;
        double latitudeStations;
        double longitudeStations;
        final RadioData[] mRadioData = new RadioData[1];
       //String radioFinderURL = "http://data.fcc.gov/lpfmapi/rest/v1/lat/" + latitude + "/long/" + longitude + "?format=json&secondchannel=true";
       //String HTTPRadioURL = "https://transition.fcc.gov/fcc-bin/fmq?state=&call=&city=&arn=&serv=FC&vac=3&freq=0.0&fre2=107.9&facid=&asrn=&class=&dkt=&list=0&dist=100&dlat2="
          //      + latitude + "&mlat2=&slat2=&NS=N&dlon2="
           //     + longitude +"&mlon2=&slon2=&EW=W&size=9";
        String radioFinderURL = "http://dredaycreative.com/json/radioData.json";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(radioFinderURL)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG,jsonData);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        mRadioData[0] = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);

                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught: ", e);
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught:", e);
                }
            }
        });








    }

    private RadioData getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject radioData = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String callSign;
        double latitudeStations;
        double longitudeStations;
        int frequency;
        JSONArray jsonArray = radioData.getJSONArray("array");
        for(int i =0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            callSign = radioData.getJSONObject(i+"")
                    .getJSONArray("array").getJSONObject(i).getString("FIELD1");
            frequency = Integer.parseInt(radioData.getJSONObject(i + "")
                    .getJSONArray("array").getJSONObject(i).getString("FIELD2"));
            longitudeStations = Double.parseDouble(radioData.getJSONObject(i+"")
                    .getJSONArray("array").getJSONObject(i).getString("FIELD20"));
            latitudeStations = Double.parseDouble(radioData.getJSONObject(i+"")
                    .getJSONArray("array").getJSONObject(i).getString("FIELD24"));
        Log.i(TAG, "From JSON: " + callSign + frequency + latitudeStations  + longitudeStations);

            if {
            distanceBetween(double latitude, double longitude, double latitudeStations, double longitudeStations, float[] results) <100km
        RadioData currently = new RadioData();
            }
        }
            return new RadioData();



    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();


    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


}
```

UPDATED CODER AFTER COMMENT AT 7:55PMCMT 8/17/15

Okay thank you for your help! I switched it up in this way am I getting warmer, ha?

```
 private RadioData getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject radioData = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        static void distanceBetween;
        String callSign;
        double latitudeStations;
        double longitudeStations;
        int frequency;
        private int mRadius = distanceBetween(double latitude, double longitude, double latitudeStations, double longitudeStations, float[] results)


        callSign = radioData.getJSONObject(i + "")
                  .getJSONObject(i).getString("FIELD1");
            frequency = Integer.parseInt(radioData.getJSONObject(i + "")
                    .getJSONObject(i).getString("FIELD2"));
            longitudeStations = Double.parseDouble(radioData.getJSONObject(i + "")
                    .getJSONObject(i).getString("FIELD20"));
            latitudeStations = Double.parseDouble(radioData.getJSONObject(i + "")
                   .getJSONObject(i).getString("FIELD24"));
        Log.i(TAG, "From JSON: " + callSign + frequency + latitudeStations  + longitudeStations);

        if{
            500 >= mRadius;
            RadioData radioData = new RadioData();
            }
        }
            return new RadioData();



    }
```

Comment: start with the begining. your json parsing does not work. For one, your data is a json array, not a jsonobject. then, there is never a `array` key anywhere in the file. This is much simpler than that.

Comment: okay updated it! but how would I tell the JSON to only print certain ones to the radioData file?